# Ajax request extremely slow

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't know why, but my Javascript is extremely slow and takes like five minutes to finish properly, you sometimes refresh the pages and some requests haven't been processed.

I already used async:true hoping that it will process a little bit faster but it doesn't. Here's the code I am using to save each element on inside #myspace.

```
cn = document.getElementById("myspace").childNodes;
        for (var t = 0; t < cn.length; t++) {
            if (cn[t].nodeType == 1) {
                var n = {
                    id: cn[t].id,
                    left: cn[t].style.left,
                    top: cn[t].style.top
                };
                $.ajax({
                    data: n,
                    url: "/Application/Ajax/__ajaxProfile.php?a=SavePosition",
                    type: "post",
                    cache: true,
                    async: true,
                    success: function (e) {}
                })
            }
        }
        e("Please wait for everything to save, it might take more than a minute.");

        setInterval(function () {

        if ($.active == 0) {

            $('#close-modal').show();

        }

        }, 10);
```

Anyone knows why it's been processed so slowly and a decent solution for this?

Comment: You are showing your `close-modal` every 10 miliseconds. Seems a bit excessive.

Comment: Did you mean to do `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`? That might be blocking the thread. Else: how many childnodes does `#myspace` have and how fast is the server reacting to the request (check it in developer tools)?

Comment: I did that to show it when all ajax requests were finished, even without that it processes extremely slow. Edit: The less childnodes there are, faster it processes, I don't know if it's because I'm making a request for each node or whatever.

Comment: use jQuery.async loop to take childrens it will speed up... http://erickrdch.com/2012/05/asynchronous-loop-with-jquery-deferred.html

Comment: `async` is standard set to `true` according to the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), just saying.

Comment: If I used setTimeout it would not verify real-time if all the ajax requests were processed.

Comment: How many requests you sending?. How long it takes to save without ajax?

Comment: just tell us how many nodes there are. if you make like 10,000 AJAX requests, then it is obvious that the process will take time. i would make async: false, just to make a progress bar and check how fast the process goes.

Comment: There's actually 40 nodes and it takes 3 minutes to process them all. If you leave the page before that, some aren't saved. Edit: Is there any way to process them in a bundle?

Comment: Collect all required data and send as one request

Comment: Yes, just put it all in a multi-dimansional array for example and send that to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var n_array=new Array();

for (var t = 0; t < cn.length; t++) {
    if (cn[t].nodeType == 1) {
        var n = {
            id: cn[t].id,
            left: cn[t].style.left,
            top: cn[t].style.top
         };
         n_array.push(n);     
     }
}

$.ajax({
   data: n_array,
   url: "/Application/Ajax/__ajaxProfile.php?a=SavePosition",
   type: "post",
   cache: true,
   success: function (e) {}
})
```

should be WAY faster, and produce less traffic. ofc you'll have to change the processing code a little...